# App crashing during Core Data standard migration without error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

When trying to update core data using standard migration, the app crashes without an error message. It has all the standard log messages up to this:

```
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZENTRY(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZLOCATION, ZBOOKMARKED, ZCREATIONDATE, ZENTRYID, ZMESSAGE, ZSECTIONIDENTIFIER, ZTICDSSYNCID, ZVERSION) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZISINPHOTOLIBRARY, t0.ZLARGETHUMBNAIL, t0.ZMOVIE, t0.ZORIGINALHEIGHT, t0.ZORIGINALIMAGE, t0.ZORIGINALWIDTH, t0.ZSCREENSIZEIMAGE, t0.ZTHUMBNAIL, t0.ZTYPE, t0.ZENTRY, t0.Z_FOK_ENTRY FROM ZMEDIA t0
```

It lingers on that for a few seconds, before crashing to the home screen with no further log message.

The code before the crash is:

```
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *pscOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                                nil];
```

Then it crashes on this line:

```
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:pscOptions error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
```

It doesn't even reach that unresolved error line.

Comment: So... what does stepping through in the debugger tell you?

Comment: @JodyHagins I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Setting breakpoints has the same effect. If that's incorrect, how do i 'step through in the debugger'?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the debugger, step through the code until it crashes.  Examine all the variables and program state to see why it is crashing.  You will see a stack backtrace.  You can access the entire environment which contains a ton of information, way more than your log message.

Comment: I don't know what I'm looking for here. The line it crashes on is definitely the addPersistentStoreWithType, so the last breakpoint i can set (which would get called) is on that line.

Comment: Yeah... so you need to do some debugging work.  Look at the stack trace, examine the state of the stack and objects that are being accessed at the time of the crash.  If these concepts are foreign to you, then I suggest googling for some tutorials on using the xcode debugger.

Comment: I've done that, but nothing is standing out at me. I have the debugging enabled for core data, it's giving me the above messages, it's just not telling me why it crashes on the `addPersistentStoreWithType` line.

Comment: If it's what I think it is then you are running out of memory.  The code doesn't return.  It just crashes out.  Try profiling the app while migrating as see if you are getting memory warning flags.  Core data puts the whole database into memory when migrating.  This can be a show-stopper with large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've got the same issue I described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13876952/1032151) (You modified model without creating a new model version).

And a great helper for you could be wrapping line with problem in @try @catch block and see what it catches like this:

```
@try
{
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:pscOptions error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}
@catch(NSException* ex)
{
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", ex);
}
```

It helps understanding problems.